# How to return a single entry from populate method in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Mongoose and I'm using virtual fields with a Retailer Schema. A retailer can have many items. Now when I use the populate method to populate the items for a retailer, it returns a list of items.

```
const { items }= await Retailers.findById(retailerID).populate('items');
```

Can we return only one entry of item based on an item ID param provided in the request URL? I know we can filter the result from JavaScript but I was wondering if this can be done through Mongoose Methods itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. 
You would want to use `select` method instead of `populate`. 
In your case it would be:

`const { items }= await Retailers.findById(retailerID).select('items');`

Comment: no this doesn't work, it only returns an _id field whereas I want the entire object with that id

Comment: have you tried:

`const retailer = await Retailers.findOne({retailerID});`

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose **virtuals** are not actually persisted into the database and acts and computed properties. Currently they do not allow for **query conditions** or **selection** at the document level.

Filtering the `items` array via JS after the query is one way to make this work.

Comment: no this doesn't work either. Rn I'm doing this to achieve my purpose,

 

   const { items }= await Retailers.findById(retailerID).populate('items');

   


 const item = items.find((item) => {
      return item._id == ID;
    })

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work?.. do u not the get  the required documents 'items` or something else

Comment: the required items are virtual fields in my schema, one retailer has many items and I can easily return a list of all the items, but I need one specific item based on the ID that I provide. I'm using js filter method for that but I wanted to know if this can be done from mongoose methods

Comment: Tried this too, this strangely returns me the retailer not the item

Comment: @AbdulHannan Okay! This isn't working because the `items` are virtuals (didn't see that in the question earlier) which are not persisted in Mongodb. And are not available for query conditions like above. Although it allows for a precondition, but in this case the way u are filtering the items array using JS is the solution.